# python 3.5 update sqlite3 version

Tags: python, sqlite

I have installed python 3.5.3 installed on my Windows machine. I check the SQLite version via the command sqlite3.sqlite_version. It is version 3.8.11.

My question is how can I update the SQLite version to 3.26? I wasn't sure if there was a 3rd party library or if I need to update sqlite3 library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just update the sqlite in the system by a newer version. Python will use it. It is not 3rd party. It is included in Python. I am not completely sure but I think it is a dynamically loaded library installed with Python but that you can upgrade by yourself. At least in my system different Python versions report the same sqlite3 version.

Comment: Yup. I downloaded the latest windows binary sqlite3.dll and replace it in the Python DLLs directory and it worked.

Comment: For anyone looking for the dll path, try looking in `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\sqlite3.dll` or something similar