# How to upgrade sqlite3 version in windows 10

Tags: python, database, sqlite, upgrade

How to upgrade sqlite3 version? I use pycharm to code in windows 10. 
The output of this print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)  is 3.21.0

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 3):

Download the latest release from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
and manually copy `sqlite3.dll` into Python's `DLLs` subfolder.

According to:

- [StackOverflow Question "Can I use a later of version of sqlite3 with python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978425/can-i-use-a-later-of-version-of-sqlite3-with-python)
- [StackOverflow Question "python update sqlite3 version"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382087/python-3-5-update-sqlite3-version)

Comment: If you're using Anaconda on Windows 10, the relevant DLL for sqlite3 will be in `Library/bin` instead of `DLLs`.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to find the binaries for your system on the official website's download page.

https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: I don't see instruction there how to apply them

Comment: Here are the instructions: https://www.guru99.com/download-install-sqlite.html